# How to get the picker value in controller using Titanium Alloy?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How can we get the selected picker value in controller and do the validation of the selected value.

View:

```
  <Picker id="countryPicker" class="picker">
            <PickerRow title="Select a Country"/>
            <PickerRow title="India"/>
            <PickerRow title="China"/>
  </Picker>
```

Controller:

```
var countryname = $countryPicker.value();
alert("country: "+ countryname);
$.planWin.open();
```

Did validation done in controller or some other module?

Comment: value is a property not a function ! and what does mean validation ? you have to explain more...

Comment: I tried $countryPicker.value, for this also I'm not able to get the selected value. Validation mean not validation whether the value is selected for the question or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an event listener for change event fired when selecting a picker item ...

```
$.countryPicker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
 //do your stuff here 
});
```

on change event you can access selected item using event object (e) :

```
e.column, e.rowIndex, ...
```

refer to the official [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker-event-change) fro more information and use cases ...